# Adding new line after closing XML tag

Tags: ruby

I know there are some great xml parsing modules out there, but before using them I wanted to give a go at working up my own, very simplistic one.

All I want is for any closing tag to have a newline character at the end. I've tried a few things with gsub, which has let me replace a closing tag with a newline (which actually makes for a decently readable format from the unformatted paragraph of xml I gave it). I can't yet figure out how to either append a "\n" to the existing regex match or save the matched value to a variable and reinsert it with a newline added.

Again, I know there are XML parsing modules that will do a far better job than I will, but I'd like to see if I'm at least on the right path with my logic, or is there a better (from scratch) way.

Comment: O.M.G., don't try to reinvent that wheel, especially trying to use regular expressions. If you are 100% in control of the incoming XML content you *might* have a chance of making it work, but if it's XML from the wild it will crush your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768223/ruby-regexp-to-extract-specific-elements-in-an-xml-string/16654826#16654826

Answer (score 3):

Wanting to do it the hard way is admirable, and something every programmer does at least once, but it's terribly error-prone.

I'd really recommend building on a parser because it'll get you down the road a whole lot farther with a lot of less hassle:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml><t1/><t2>foo</t2></xml>
EOT

doc.each do |node|
  node.replace(node.to_s << "\n") unless node.text?
end

puts doc.to_xml
```

Which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <t1/>
  <t2>foo</t2>
</xml>
```

The problem with the naive "I'll do it with a pattern" approach is you can run into [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) blocks:

```
<![CDATA[ This can contain > < " & <foo></bar> ]]>
```

Try processing some XML with that embedded between tags using a pattern, and then see how long it takes you to write code to trap the problem, or unwind the damage done, and you'll give up in disgust.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` is a good enough solution:

```
xml.gsub(/(<\/[^>]+>)/, '\1\n')
```

Comment: Close but not quite there: `'<xml><foo><![CDATA[<foo></foo> ]]></foo></xml>'.gsub(/(<\/[^>]+>)/, '\1\n')
=> "<xml><foo><![CDATA[<foo></foo>\\n ]]></foo>\\n<xml>"`. Remember also that tags can cross lines and have intervening white-space.